# Recurring payment stays on hold on Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, recurring-billing, laravel-cashier

I have integrated stripe subscription on our website on recurring basis. Every thing is working fine but there is an issue with LIVE recurring payments.

### issue

-> Whenever stripe tries to do recurring payment from customers account it shows the following error on stripe dashboard and it stays like this for 3 days and then became succeded.

error message : " The user has completed the payment and Stripe is waiting for the funds from their bank.
Stripe is currently processing the payment. ".

-> I have checked this with multiple bank cards but still the issue is there with every bank card.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: What type of payment method are you using? This sounds like a pending payment for the type you're using and is likely documented. I think for help with this specific subscription/payment method you should reach out to Stripe Support so they can help you understand why this happens: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: ok, i'm using card payment method @NolanH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue i had discussed with stripe support team. For Indian users, it's a regulation of STRIPE that they wait for 72 hours before charging the user to downstream issues.

Here is the documentation where it's clearly mentioned.

https://stripe.com/docs/india-recurring-payments

[image]